# Trouble Marshalling the Ui Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

I'm trying to update the text of a label from a seperate class on a separate thread. The other class raises an event which is handled here

```
    Private Sub handleChangeUI(ByVal sender As System.Object)
    Dim ytde As Data_Entry_Form.YTD = CType(sender, Data_Entry_Form.YTD)

    UpdateExcelLabel(ytde.LabelMessage)
End Sub
```

And in the updateExcelLabel method I was hoping to change the label's text with the following

```
 Private Delegate Sub updateExcelDelegate(txt As String)
Public Sub UpdateExcelLabel(text As String)
    If Me.lblExcel.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Dim del As New updateExcelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateExcelLabel)
        Me.lblExcel.BeginInvoke(del, text)
    Else
        Me.lblExcel.Visible = True
        Me.lblExcel.Text = text
        Me.lblExcel.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason the Me.lblExcel.InvokeRequired is always returning true. I'm still very new when it comes to delegates and multi-threading so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), `BeginInvoke` runs the delegate on the thread the control was created on, but it is asynchronous, so there is no guarantee the delegate has begun to run before the next time `handleChangeUI` is called.

I have always used `Invoke` in this situation, rather than `BeginInvoke`.